# How do I deploy a Discord bot to a VPS?

Tags: python, bots, discord

I wish to deploy this particular bot ( https://github.com/Cog-Creators/Red-DiscordBot ) to a VPS ( https://plox.host/ ). I have purchased a virtual server there and it is operational.

I am using Terminal on macOS. What exactly should I do to make the bot run 24*7??

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to VPS using SSH
2. Install updates
3. Install git
4. Install the bot from GitHub

Comment: What exact commands am I supposed to run to do steps 2/3/4?

Comment: it depends on installed OS onto VPS. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the README.md file in your link for the answer. Always read the readme file when you're jumping into something new.

And once the bot is running, it should run until something tells it not to.

Comment: If you're going to downvote a answer that answers the question, feel free to say why you downvoted it.

Comment: I read the README.md, and it does not have any instructions for hosting the bot on a VPS. Edit: I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: @AragornTelcontar It doesn't specify a VPS because a VPS is just a virtual computer. You need to find the instructions for the OS that is on your VPS and follow those.

Comment: If it answers your question, please mark it as the answer. If not, let us know.